# map onclick disabling scrollbar of parent div

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

i have a lots of div inside my modal. a map is also a part of it. 
Scrollbar of my modal is disappearing when i click on map div. Dont know what is happening.

any Idea?

Comment: show us your relevant code(html,css ...)

Comment: i have added the HTML code,

Comment: i got the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery(".mCustomScrollbar").mCustomScrollbar("scrollTo","top");
```

make sure you declare jQuery at the beginning.